# how to transfer an audio stream to a video stream?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Tee.png)

```
PS C:\Users\RI\Desktop\Movie> ffprobe mov002.mpg 
Input #0, mpeg, from 'mov002.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.26, start: 31.949778, bitrate: 2258447 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Audio: mp3, 0 channels, fltp
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
```

Stream #0:0 should be a video stream, but it is parsed as an audio stream

how to transfer the audio stream to a video stream

Comment: Consider increasing the value for the `-analyzeduration` and `-probesize` options, such as `ffprobe -analyzeduration 10M -probesize 10M mov002.mpg`

Comment: It has no effect